# SSRS "Go to report" Drill Action gets Slower Over Time

Tags: reporting-services, reporting, ssrs-2012, dashboard

We have a reporting solution that utilizes the "Go to report" drill actions in SSRS to move from report to report.  This allows the reporting solution to act like a dashboard that contains multiple tabs and views, and it allows our users to interact with their data intuitively.

However, we're noticing that after clicking through the different reports for awhile (20 reports or so), the reporting solution gets slower and slower.  Reports that once returned in 3 seconds now take 10 seconds to return.  If we click around the reporting solution longer, that same report can take up to 20 seconds to return.

I have a feeling that it has something to do with SSRS storing all the parameters for each report we've clicked.  We pass about 15 parameters each time, and in order for the back button on the browser to work, SSRS needs to store in memory each of those previous reports' parameters.  This means that the more reports we click into, the more data the browser needs to restore.  If we close out of the browser and re-open the reporting solution, that reports return quickly again as expected.

Is there a way to tell SSRS to stop holding on to so much data?  Can we set the maximum amount of "backs" possible to 2 or 3?  Or is my issue something else entirely?  I'm certainly at a loss!  Thanks!

Edit - A co-worker mentioned that "_viewstate" might have something to do with this issue.  Maybe this helps someone answer this question?

Edit 2 - Our best solution so far is to use the "Go to URL" action instead.  This refreshes the page and eliminates the stack of history that seems to bog down the system...

Comment: That is certainly a complex way to use SSRS. Have you used event viewer on SSRS and run a performance log? Is this a standalone server, or a load balanced cluster? Do you get messages in logs like "Failed state validation exception" (I don't remember the specific error I've seen but it's similar) ?

Comment: I have not tried to use an event viewer (I'll be honest, I don't even know how).  I believe this is a standalone server, but I'm not sure.  But once you mentioned it, I do remember seeing errors in the ReportServer log.  It seems every time I load a report, I get a new line of code like the following:  

processing!ReportServer_0-5!1eb4!03/21/2019-17:52:08:: e ERROR: Throwing Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportProcessingException: , Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportProcessingException: There is no data for the field at position 26.;

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't have 50 rep yet (so I can't comment) I see this "There is no data for the field at position 26" at the end. I would examine your dataset to see what's coming over. IE, datatype = datatype or in other words, maybe it's coming as a string and trying to convert to an int, or something like that. Yes, it says 'no data' but SSRS is weird and wild and sometimes you have to take things like error messages and toss them out the window.

To expand on the 'no data for the field' it could be a MISSING field in the dataset (it's defined, but the query isn't picking it up). That's what that error specifically means, but I've seen other things too.